# Code appeared automatically in viewDidUnload

Tags: ios, objective-c

I simply created a new subclass of UIViewController.
Added some UI objects on it in interface builder, and
created outlets for these UI objects and made respective connections.

Then, suddenly, I saw this code generated automatically for me in the
implementation of my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    imageView = nil;  
    scrollView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

I didn't notice this happening before, was it supposed to happen like this? why?

Comment: Thats how new xcode now works. It automatically adds those nil statements in viewDidUnload method.

Comment: @Janak Nirmal: Yes, but my question was why? I am already using ARC, so I thought it would take care of it + the IBOutlets are declared as __weak ...

Comment: Actually if your deployment target is below 6 than it will automatically generate viewDidLoad method for you and put those statements. So this should be the case. Though it would be weak/strong reference it will add those statements that I confirm as I tested it by creating test project

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall it getting auto-generated, but viewDidUnload is deprecated in iOS 6 so you can just delete it (assuming you're targeting 6.0+).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of viewDidUnload method is to release the resource whatever you have created in the viewDidLoad method so it is doing exact opposite to the viewDidUnload method . Xcode provides the facility to release the allocated resource automatically so you are finding that code into the viewDidUnload method. For more information you can follow the following link:
[viewDidUnload refernce.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload)

Comment: Yes, but my question was why it was doing so... (setting pointers as nil, as I mentioned I am using ARC+outlets were __weak)

Answer (score 0):

It's called when `Received memory warning.`

```
 - (void)viewDidUnload NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0,6_0); // Called after the view controller's view is released and set to nil. For example, a memory warning which causes the view to be purged. Not invoked as a result of -dealloc.
```

By the ways, If you want release sth. when recevied memory warning, you can use

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning; // Called when the parent application receives a memory warning. On iOS 6.0 it will no longer clear the view by default.
```